# показать время начала и время конца

Tags: php

У меня есть массив с временем(12:20,12:21,12:22,...,12:42,12:43) и статусом(0,0,1,...,0,0), если статус 1 ничего делать не нужно, если 0 нужно показать время начала и время конца. Например
12:20 - 12:22
12:42 - 12:43

```
    $sql = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `serviceHistory` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
    $sql->execute();
    $history = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($history as $history) {
        if ($history['status'] != 1) {
            if ($history['status'] == 0) {
                // тут дата
                $this->forNumber++;
            }
        }
        
    }

    //$this->connect->prepare("DELETE FROM `serverHistory`")->execute();
    //$this->connect->prepare("DELETE FROM `serviceHistory`")->execute();

    response::create($this->response);
```

Comment: Так в чём проблема собственно?..

Comment: не знаю как это сделать, нужна помощь

Comment: какой формат у исходных данных?

Comment: mysql, вот код - https://imgur.com/a/mzD4Zoe

Comment: так приведите в вопросе тестовые данные.

Comment: `$sql = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `serviceHistory` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
        $sql->execute();
        $history = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($history as $history) {
            if ($history['status'] != 1) {
                if ($history['status'] == 0) {
                    // тут нужно все делать
                    $this->forNumber++;
                }
            }
            
        }
        response::create($this->response);`

Comment: забыл про базу - вот база https://imgur.com/a/tXIejP4

Comment: перенесите код в вопрос. Добавьте образец полученного массива, с которым можно что-то делать. Например, результат вывода var_export()

Comment: Если вам нужна помощь с запросом, создайте тестовую базу на http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил код